# How to know the memory size of a trie?

Tags: d

Trie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

I want to impl different kinds of Trie and compare their memory size.

Is there a generic function like a.memoryUsage() in core or std? Or need to impl different function in every class.

Answer (score 1):

Since trie is a recursive structure, you can traverse the top of the trie and keep adding the memory of each variable in each trie to a **sum**.

Write a general traversal algorithm that accepts a template of tries, a function pointer and for each type of tries write a function that calculates the sum of memory of that sub-trie.

That is of course you want the specific memory usage of a specific kind of trie.

The general memory usage can be described with big O notation by another name: [Space complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity)